# How to handle Back Button to remove current fragment In MvvmCross

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

My MainMenu is the first launched activity or page which will show the MainPage as the Fragment

in this MainMenu,

a) it has a Left Drawer. When user click on an item in the drawer, it will be displayed as fragment.

In this MainPage,
b) it has dropdown menu in Action-Bar. when user click an item in the menu
it will be displayed as fragment

The Problem:

1) User click an item in MainPage(b) :Action_bar dropdown menu, how to remove or not to show this current display fragment WHEN user click the back button and show the main page content

I tried below code, it does not work

```
public override void OnBackPressed()
{
  if (DrawerLayout != null && DrawerLayout.IsDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.Start))

        DrawerLayout.CloseDrawers();
  else
        base.OnBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the fragment to the backstack of the fragment manager with this:

```
var ft = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
ft.AddToBackStack(fragInfo.Tag);
ft.Commit();
```

I would recommend looking into the Android sample of MvvmCross. It handles a lot of things by default, like the backstack.
https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/tree/master/Samples

Comment: I followed the link. can use the above code  if the clicked-item is in Drawer of MainMenu or in dropdwon menu in action-basr in a fragment like mainpage?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that question, but it has a drawer and you can do menu action stuff.

Comment: I click an item in the drop-down menu in action-bar, it displays an fragment. Now, when user click the back button, how can I remove the current fragment ? I used the above OnBackPressed(), it does not work.

Comment: But do you as in the sample, add the fragment to the backstack? If it is not added to the backstack it won't work. Note: you need to be on MvvmCross 4.0.0-beta2 for this to work.

Comment: didnt mean to open a new thread. I realized I need to close the current activity which is not a fragment. For above question, I am not sure if fragment is the same as activity since this activity is not registered. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To add fragment to backstack it is possible to specify **AddToBackStack = true in MvxFragmentPresentation attribute**:

```
[MvxFragmentPresentation(typeof(YourViewModel), Resource.Id.your_content_frame, AddToBackStack = true)]
```