# How to close the current Activity when user click Back button

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

In my project, I have implemented the MvvmCross to display fragment as page.

1. I have a Main Menu page which has Left drawer. It is defaulted to show Main Page as fragment.
2. In the main page, I have a drop-down menu in its action-bar. It will launch the respective page when user clicks an item
3. User clicks an item and it launches the Company info page.
4. Now, the Company info page is the current page being displayed.

**Problem :**

How to close the current display page which is company info page  when user click the back button? When this page is closed, the main page will be seen.

where to write the logic to handle the back button ?

In Main Menu.cs or Main Page.cs  or Company info.cs

```
 public override void OnBackPressed()
 {

 }
```

Comment: You already asked this in this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32286428/how-to-handle-back-button-to-remove-current-fragment-in-mvvmcross

Comment: @Martijn, For your link, it was a Fragment and I think your solution should work . In this above case, it is launching an Activity from click an item in drop-down menu. I am not sure if activity is the same as Fragment. I need to close this currently Activity. How to close it so that the MainPage in the back can be seen again. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can call the `finish();` method of the activity. Do this in your 'Company' activity. That will close the current activity and returns to the previous (as far as I know).

More Infos about the method: [Xamarin Developer](http://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.Activity.Finish/)